# `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, &rlim)` returns `rlim.rlim_cur` of `0` which is outside of the defined range?

Tags: linux, ulimit, setrlimit

The man-page to `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, &rlim)` says on successful return `rlim.rlim_cur` (and `rlim.rlim_cur`) will contain a value in the range of `1` to `40` or `RLIM_INFINITY` (which I think is `(unsigned long)-1`), but instead it always contains `0` for me. What does `0` mean here?

I tried to do change the limits using `ulimit -Se10` but that just gives me `ulimit: scheduling priority: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument` for positive values and `ulimit: -1: invalid number` for negative values. (I guess it also wants the `1` to `40` range instead of the `-20` to `+19` range?) Only `ulimit -Se0` is ok, but useless. (That is for user and for root.)

What I actually want to do: Find out if I can `setpriority()` to a certain value, but don't actually set it to the value. It will be set to that value after a `fork()` (well, after two forks where I want to keep the parent in the current priority). But I want to report a possible error as early as possible.